# Why would AWS API Gateway let cached queries through to the backend?

Tags: caching, aws-api-gateway, api-design

I have a GET method in AWS Api Gateway. The cache is enabled for the stage, and works for most requests. However some requests seem to slip through to the backend no matter what I do. That is, some requests going through the API are not cached.

I have defined the parameter `a`, `b` & `c` to be cached; by checking their respective "caching"-box under the "request" settings. There are also other parameters which are not cached.

The request can either have all three parameters or just one:

```
example.com/?a=foo&b=bar&c=baz&d=qux
example.com/?a=foo&d=qux
```

`a`, `b` & `c` can take on between 3 and 25 different values. But `a` can only have one value if `b` & `c` are present. Also `b` cannot be present without `c` and vice versa.

An example, say the cache's TTL is 60 I send this between time 0 and 10:

```
example.com/?a=foo&b=bar&c=baz&d=qux
example.com/?a=quux&d=qux
example.com/?a=foo&b=quux&c=baz&d=qux
example.com/?a=foo&b=corge&c=fred&d=qux
example.com/?a=baz&d=qux
```

And then between time 30 and 40 I send the same requests and I might see the following log:

```
example.com/?a=foo&b=bar&c=baz&d=qux
example.com/?a=quux&d=qux
example.com/?a=baz&d=qux
```

So these requests were cached while the others weren't:

```
example.com/?a=foo&b=quux&c=baz&d=qux
example.com/?a=foo&b=corge&c=fred&d=qux
```

In the example above most were not cached but this is not the case in the real case; Most queries are cached. In the real case there are a fairly big number of requests coming in on the second run, about 600/s. In the first run the request-rate is about 1/s. The queries I see slipping through are among the first that would be requested by the application.

It seems unlikely that AWS API Gateway wouldn't be able to handle similar query rates (throttling is enabled at 10 000 requests and 5000 at burst) but yet it seems the first few queries the application sends slip through. Is this to be expected from API Gateway?

I was also thinking that there might be a cache size issue but increasing the cache does not seem to help.

So what reasons could there be for API Gateway to let seemingly cached requests slip through to the backend?

UPDATE: The nature of the application, which creates the requests is that it starts a request chain. Meaning, there are about 500-600 applications which all start at the same time. When they make a handful of asynchronously and then a chain of about 300-500 requests (synchronously).

With this in mind, The burst rate at 0 s is probably much higher. The ~600 requests/s stated above the average of ~36 000 queries over 60 s. Most of the requests would be done at the beginning of those 60 s but I don't have a number on the exact rate. An estimate might be about 1000-2000 requests/s for the first seconds and maybe even more (say 3000+) for the first second.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this one?

Comment: I wish I could say definitely yes, but not really. I managed to mitigate the effects and minimize the number of requests sent to the backend. But I don't know exactly why this happened. I can write an answer with what I found out and what I did.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I still don't know why this happens but I did manage to minimize the number of requests that slipped through.

I did this by having the requesting application delay the start (I explained the nature of the start sequence in the update to the question) by some random time. I let the application pick a random start time between 0 and 3 minutes to avoid spikes to API Gateway.

This didn't eliminate the phenomenon of requests slipping through but it lowered the number from about 500-1500 over 60s to between 0-10 over 3 minutes. Something my backend could easily handle, compared to the 1000+ over 60 s which was on the edge.

It seems to me that when API Gateway is flooded with a large number of requests over a short time it will just pass these requests through. I am surprised (and a little skeptical) that these numbers would be so large as to cause problems for AWS but that is what I see.

Perhaps this can be solved by changing the throttling levels, but I found no difference when playing around with it (mind you, I'm no expert!).